# POST request using Swift Combine without return doesn't work with AnyPublisher<Void, Error>

Tags: ios, swift, http, swiftui, combine

I have a POST request to send a text message to the user that doesn't return anything, but the status code. I try to return AnyPublisher<Void, CustomError> but it won't work.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBB5X.png)

This is what my generic request method looks like:

```
func request<T>(_ req: NetworkRequest) -> AnyPublisher<T, NetworkError> where T: Decodable, T: Encodable {
    let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    sessionConfig.timeoutIntervalForRequest = TimeInterval(req.requestTimeout ?? requestTimeout)

    guard let url = URL(string: req.url) else {
        // Return a fail publisher if the url is invalid
        return AnyPublisher(
            Fail<T, NetworkError>(error: NetworkError.badURL("Invalid Url"))
        )
    }
    // We use the dataTaskPublisher from the URLSession which gives us a publisher to play around with.
    return URLSession.shared
        .dataTaskPublisher(for: req.buildURLRequest(with: url))
        .tryMap { output in
            // throw an error if response is nil
            guard output.response is HTTPURLResponse else {
                throw NetworkError.serverError(code: 0, error: "Server error")
            }
            return output.data
        }
        .decode(type: T.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
        .mapError { error in
            // return error if json decoding fails
            NetworkError.invalidJSON(String(describing: error))
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Comment: What does "it won't work" mean? Also where's the post request in all this? A data task is not going to do a post request.

Comment: twilioService
            .generateCode(to: formattedPhoneNo)
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { (completion) in
                switch completion {
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("ERROR: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                case .finished:
                    return
                }
            }, receiveValue: { (res) in
                print("RESPONSE: \(res)")
            })
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }

Comment: Xcode doesn't accuse any error o the post request call, the error is on the implementation method which is available in the image attached to the post.

Comment: Well don't attach an image. No pictures of code please. If code is needed to describe the issue post it as code (text).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the primary issue is that you're trying to turn `AnyPublisher<T,NetworkError>` into `AnyPublisher<Void,NetworkError>`.

You could do:

```
service.request(request).map { _ in () }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

Comment: I've tried that before but it still shows an error: Unable to infer type of a closure parameter '_' in the current context

Comment: It'd be helpful if you could update the question with what type `createRequest` returns -- it's not clear from the included code what the associated generic will be.

Comment: It returns a networkRequest: func createRequest(token: String, environment: BuildEnvironment) -> NetworkRequest {...}, which is just a class abstracting url, headers, body, request timeout and http method.

Comment: So where is `request` inferring the generic type from?

Comment: Here is where the error is occurring:     func generateCode(to number: String) -> AnyPublisher<Void, NetworkError> {
        let endpoint = TwilioEndpoints.generateCode(number: "+55\(number)")
        let request = endpoint.createRequest(token: token ?? "",
                                             environment: environment)
        
        return service.request(request)
    }

Comment: That's what you included in the attached image to your post, right? Can you include a [mre]?